# Xamarin access to a file from Core

Tags: file, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have some issues on a Xamarin project to access to a file from the core lib.

My file is schema.json it's located in Assets folder of the Android project and in the Resources folder of the Touch project but neither `Application.Context.Assets.Open("schema.json")` or `System.IO.File.ReadAllText("schema.json")` works.

Do you know how do access to a specific file/folder from the core lib ?

PS : I am using MVVM Cross if it can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Xamarin.Forms and trying to do this in a cross-platform manner, you can use the examples in [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/) guide, like so:

```
var assembly = typeof(LoadResourceText).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("WorkingWithFiles.PCLTextResource.txt");
string text = "";
using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader (stream)) {
    text = reader.ReadToEnd ();
}
```

To do this, you'll need to add your file to your Forms PCL project, with a Build Action of `EmbeddedResource`.

For loading platform specific strings, near the bottom you can see the standard practice of using IoC to get an implementation that can access the platform-bundled file content.

Comment: Thank you I could access to my file with 
Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("<namespace>.format.json");